# Choosing option from dropbox with NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I need to choose an option from dropbox in one site with NSUrlConnection and then get the source code of the page, how do I actually choose the option with code or is it possible?

Comment: With dropbox I mean a box what you click then it shows menu where you can choose item from. The one which uses <option></option> in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what NSURLConnection does.

All NSURLConnection does is request a resource—in this case, a webpage on Dropbox's site. You then receive that resource (the text of the page) in the response.

You can't *interact* with the page at all, because NSURLConnection is not a web view. It's *just* a connection. There is no DOM, no JavaScript, no concept of forms or actions or inputs or anchors. You send a request and get data back—that's it.

You need a WebView or UIWebView (hidden or not) and you need to interact with that view's document through JavaScript. Or, better yet, [use the Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) rather than poking their webpages.

Comment: Ahh with dropbox I meant combobox, dropdown menu if you call it that. But what is the difference between WebView and UIWebView?

Comment: WebView is one of the WebKit classes on the Mac; UIWebView is a class in UIKit on iOS.